# Sending Files over IpV6

Tags: vb.net, sockets, networking, tcp, ipv6

I want to send a file over the internet with a tcp connection. My code handles this for IpV4 well (creddits here go to http://technotif.com/creating-simple-tcpip-server-client-transfer-data-using-c-vb-net/, i just changed minor things to correct the file output)
I tried to use this with a friend of mine, but his router is uteer garbage, and it cant forward any ports whatsoever and wont even work with upnp. It is set to IpV6 as well, and as far as I know IPv6 doesnt need anymore port forwarding since every device has its own public ip.

sadly my program doesnt work with IPv6 adresses, and I have a hard time finding any information regarding this topic.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private nSockets As ArrayList


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim IPHost As IPHostEntry
    IPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName())
    lblStatus.Text = "My IP address is " +
 IPHost.AddressList(0).ToString()
    nSockets = New ArrayList()
    Dim thdListener As New Thread(New ThreadStart _
    (AddressOf listenerThread))
    thdListener.Start()
End Sub



Public Sub listenerThread()

    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Dim tcpListener As New TcpListener(7080)
    Dim handlerSocket As Socket
    Dim thdstHandler As ThreadStart
        Dim thdHandler As Thread
        tcpListener.Start()
        Do
            handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()
            If handlerSocket.Connected Then
                lbConnections.Items.Add(
                handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() +
                "connected.")
                SyncLock (Me)
                    nSockets.Add(handlerSocket)
                End SyncLock
                thdstHandler = New ThreadStart(AddressOf _
                handlerThread)
                thdHandler = New Thread(thdstHandler)
                thdHandler.Start()
            End If
        Loop
End Sub

Public Sub handlerThread()

        Dim handlerSocket As Socket
        handlerSocket = nSockets(nSockets.Count - 1)
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = New _
NetworkStream(handlerSocket)
    Dim blockSize As Int16 = 16
        Dim thisRead As Int16
        Dim dataByte(blockSize) As Byte
        SyncLock Me
            ' Only one process can access the
            ' same file at any given time
            Dim fileStream As Stream
            fileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Whatever.file")
            While (True)
                thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataByte,
0, dataByte.Length)
                fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead)
                If thisRead = 0 Then Exit While
            End While
            fileStream.Close()
            networkStream.Close()
        End SyncLock
        lbConnections.Items.Add("File Written")
    handlerSocket = Nothing
End Sub
```

How do i make it IPv6 capable?

Forgot to put in my client, what do i have to change here to make it work? Since even with the changes to my server, its still not connecting properly.

```
Private Sub Sendfile()
    Dim filebuffer As Byte()
    Dim fileStream As Stream
    fileStream = File.OpenRead(tbFilename.Text)
    ' Alocate memory space for the file
    ReDim filebuffer(fileStream.Length)
    fileStream.Read(filebuffer, 0, fileStream.Length)
    ' Open a TCP/IP Connection and send the data
    Dim clientSocket As New TcpClient(tbServer.Text, 7080)
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream
    networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
    networkStream.Write(filebuffer, 0, fileStream.Length)
    networkStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` <- This already indicates that you're doing something wrong. The check illegal cross-thread calls check is there to stop you from doing something bad, so instead of disabling that check you should do it right from the beginning. Remove that line again and make your code [**thread-safe**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201704011458227850227) instead.

Comment: true that, i admitt, this code was just rushed together :( i was trying something and never worked with networking code before :) but thanks for the information. I guess that must be the reason as well, why some threads stay open after the main form has been closed. ( they are still visible in taskmanager process list). Or is that for another reason? How do I correctly Abort threads after the main form has been closed?

Comment: The reason to why the threads are still alive are because they're foreground threads. Foreground threads count as a "vital" part of the application and each must be closed manually before the process can exit. -- To fix it, set each thread's [**`IsBackground` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True` before starting them. That will make them close automatically when the application closes.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the Information. Could you maybe take a look again at my edited question? I tried to fix my code for the client, but i cant make it connect to the server via IPv6. What am I doing wrong here? Is tcpclient the wrong approach and i should try it with sockets? I'm really bloody new to networking code, and kinda new to coding in general. Any help would be hugely appreciated to get this thing running over IpV6.

Comment: Actually using a `TcpClient` is the better and easier way to go (both client- and serverside). A `TcpClient` is just a wrapper for a `Socket`. It takes care of many annoying calls for you.

Comment: On the server you could try calling `tcpListener.AllowNatTraversal(True)` before you start the listener. Also, make sure the client router and the client OS support IPv6 as well.

Comment: mmmh i still cant get it to work. Is this code with the changes from your answer suppossed to be able to send the files via ipv6? Could it be that there need to be any changes to the tcpclient part?

Comment: The code in my answer is supposed to make you able to connect to another endpoint via IPv6. What data you send to that endpoint is up to you once you've established a connection. The only changes to be made on the clientside is that you should connect to an IPv6-address rather than an IPv4-address.

Comment: Have your friend try the application in his LAN (or you, if you have IPv6). If he can connect to another computer in LAN then it's his router that's blocking the connection from the outside.

Comment: Also make sure you connect to his public IPv6-address. Have him go to this site and tell you the IP-address shown at the top: http://www.useipv6.com/

Comment: Hello again! I just came to ask if you've made any progress with this? Unfortunately I don't have IPv6, nor much experience in it, so I cannot test any code, but I'd still like to try to help. -- You could try pinging your friend's IPv6-address. If that fails then it's likely there's something blocking the connection.

Comment: @VisualVincent hadnt have the time to test it, i will do so tomorrow. Thanks for your interest. I will let you know the results

Comment: @VisualVincent I tested it with another Computer also having IPv6 (over the internet, not local) and I cant connect to that computer, neither I am able to ping it. All ports are opened ( In Fact i just disabled both firewalls clientside and serverside for testing) and it simply wont let me connect to it. Router Firewalls are set to off as well. I seem to be messing something up with IPv6 in general. What is the Difference between the IPv6 Adress and the temporary IpV6 adress?

Comment: I don't know what a "temporary" IPv6 address is, but for IPv4 you have two addresses: a public and private one. The public address is your global address, i.e. the address you are connected to the internet with. The private address is the address your computer have in the LAN network.

Comment: I _think_ this is the same for IPv6, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Your listener is currently listening to IPv4-address `0.0.0.0`, which is the default when you only specify a port to the listener.

You need to use the [**`TcpListener(IPAddress, Integer)` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify [**`IPv6Any`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.ipv6any(v=vs.110).aspx) to listen to IPv6-addresses.

```
Dim tcpListener As New TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 7080)
```

As a side note you should rather use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) than an `ArrayList`. The latter is typeless and not as optimized for .NET as the former.

Comment: thanks, i cant confirm, that this is working for me, but i guess that is my fault on the client part, forgot to write that in the question, i eddited that, maybe you have enought spare time to take a look at it.